# Blank Fragment Contains Unwanted Parameters

Tags: android

I've noticed every time I create a new blank fragment it gives me some parameters at the top that I find a bit distracting and always delete. I was wondering if there's any way we can set to have these parameters not to appear when a new fragment is created?

[image]

Thanks very much.

Comment: For that you have to modify the template of file which Android Studio holds in order to create this things

Comment: Yes. Please check your class template in `Settings > File and Code Templates`

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical that will not show Blank fragment file template

Comment: Can you please check this once: http://prntscr.com/np776q

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your message. Yes, I wen to the class @Parth has mentioned on the image and removed the header from there but couldn't see any difference.

Comment: Use this link in order to create your own custom file template rather use existing template https://coderwall.com/p/fsxvyw/file-templates-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known [issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124164871) in Android Studio 3.3.1 - 3.4
It is fixed in new android studio version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. This is unchecked but Android Studio still creates those parameters since a few recent updates.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in new android studio version
See here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124164871

Comment: Cool, thanks @mit! If you'd like to edit your answer for having this comment there instead I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class and extends it from Fragment. You will get a clean class without any parameters.

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<xml layout>, container, false);

         //Your code

         return rootView;
     }
}
```